# Exception with NSUserDefaults [Swift]

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I need to store some things in a dictionary, and store them in NSUserDefaults. When I try to, however, I get this message:

DatabaseTest(2119,0x19bd00310) malloc: *** error for object 0x1740d6730: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with that same error (using Swift on iOS8), and in my case, the root cause was trying to store an `NSHTTPCookie` in `NSUserDefaults`. I suspect the NSDate in expiresDate is causing problems. Regardless, I solved it by using `NSKeyArchiver` to encode the cookie before storing it as an object.